# Trying to git rebase my last 7 commits

Tags: git, github, rebase

I'm working on a local git repo on a branch named "106"

I want to clean up my commit log so I run the command:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~7 106
```

but instead of giving me the last 7 commits it gives me around the last 30. 
I figure that's fine, I will just leave all those old commits as pick and they wont be affected. But I get this error after changing the commits I want to:

```
The previous cherry-pick is now empty, possibly due to conflict resolution. If you wish to commit it anyway, use:

git commit --allow-empty

Otherwise, please use 'git reset'
```

and it stops at some commit that happened before I even forked the repo.

I try the same rebase command except with HEAD~2 and it shows my the last 2 commits. I fixup one and pick the other and it works fine.

I do it again with HEAD~3 and it works fine.

Once I get to HEAD~6 it just shows me this huge list of commits and always gives me that cherry pick message. I am changing nothing else in the rebase command.

Comment: This happens when there is a merge commit in the chain you wish to copy-and-forget-the-originals-of. Rebasing such a chain is often a bad idea, but if you really want to do it, see, e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/q/4783599/1256452