# Interactive reabse of commits with last merge shows two extra commits in list of commits to pick/edit

Tags: git, merge

I've tried web search and found [Rebasing a Git merge commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783599/rebasing-a-git-merge-commit), where it is written:

> By default, a rebase will simply drop merge commits from the todo
> list, and put the rebased commits into a single, linear branch.

So now I understand why on `git rebase -i HEAD~9` I did not see my merged commit in a list of commits to edit/pick in interactive rebase. However, I saw two additional older commits in the list (10 commits total, merge absent). Why? Is it ok? I did rebase and now wonder maybe I better redo all recent commits. I wanted to rebase to try to remove unneeded local commits in the first place after the merge.

Last commit was merge, before that:

```
git status
Your branch and 'origin/devel' have diverged,
and have 6 and 2 different commits each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)
```

So I guess those two more is because there were 2 commits from origin that were merged. Am I correct here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No commit, once made, can ever be changed.  Hence the job that `git rebase` performs is to *copy* some existing commits (that you like to some extent, but dislike *something* about those commits) to new and improved—well, you *hope* improved, anyway—commits.  Git then sets up the *branch name*—branch names being how you tell Git to *find* commits—so that it finds the new and improved commits *instead of* the originals.

The main concerns when doing this copy-and-replace operation lie in determining *which commits to copy*.  As you've seen, you're having Git copy both your commits *and* the merged-in commits, and as you saw in the documentation, the default action during this sort of copy-and-switch-over is to *drop* merge commits entirely (due to them being unnecessary, which in turn is due to the way the copies are performed).

The Q&A you linked are, however, quite old, going back some 11 years at this point.  Git recently (within the last year or two) learned a new `git rebase` trick, which is to *re-perform merges*.  The rebase code spells this `--rebase-merges`, or `-r` for short.  You *can* use `git rebase -r` now to do some things you *could not* do with `git rebase` in the past.

> So I guess those two more is because there were 2 commits from origin that were merged. Am I correct here?

More or less, yes.  The main tricky part here is how we specify which commits Git *should* copy and which commits Git *should not* copy.

But, as the phrases *main concerns* and *main tricky part* imply, there are additional tricky parts to rebasing.  To understand what you're doing, you *must* know how commits work in Git.  It's a good idea to understand this in general, not just for rebase work.  Git is, ultimately, all about *commits*.  It is not about files, although commits contain files and humans care a lot about file contents.  Git is not about branches either, although branch names are important when it comes to finding commits.  But Git itself exists because of commits, and to work with commits.  So you need to know what a commit is and does for you.

Every Git commit is numbered: each one gets a *unique* number, that looks (but isn't) random.  This number is guaranteed to be unique,<sup>1</sup> not just in *this* repository, but in *every* Git repository, past, present, and future.  That means that if you write down the hash ID of some commit you make, and inspect any old Git repository any time and find that it has a commit with this hash ID, you know immediately that the repository you're looking at has *your* commit.

This hash ID scheme is *why* no commit can ever be changed.  If it could, we could break Git very easily by making different commits use the same hash ID.<sup>2</sup>  In any case, since we expect to *improve* our commits when we rebase them, we won't be able to keep the originals: we *have* to make at least *some* new copies that have new and different hash IDs.

Meanwhile, *each commit* stores two things:

- A commit has a full snapshot of every file that Git knew about at the time you, or whoever, made the commit.  These files are stored in a special, read-only (hashed!), Git-only format, compressed and—important to keep the repository size under control, among other reasons—*de-duplicated* against all other files in every commit in the repository.
- A commit stores *metadata:* information about the commit itself, such as who made it and when.  Here you'll find your name and email address, which Git has copied out of your `user.name` and `user.email` settings.  You will find a date-and-time stamp.  You may store a commit *log message* telling everyone *why* you made the commit.<sup>3</sup>

Now, in that metadata in each commit, Git adds something for itself.  In each commit, Git stores a list of raw hash IDs of *previous* commits.  Git calls these the *parents* of the commit.  Most commits have exactly one parent: *the* previous commit, i.e., the one commit that comes right before *this* commit.

This parent hash ID, stored in each commit, is *how* Git is able to work backwards through time, to see what you and others have done.  Let's imagine we have some commit with some hash ID `H`, that's the *latest* commit that you just made (on some branch).  Commit `H` contains a snapshot and metadata, and that metadata contains the raw hash ID of some earlier commit.  We say that `H` *points to* its parent.  Let's call the parent `G`:

```
        <-G <-H
```

The arrow coming out of `H`, pointing backwards to `G`, is the parent of `H`.  But `G` is a commit too, so it too has a snapshot and a parent—a backwards arrow—pointing to some earlier commit `F`:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

and `F` has an arrow pointing back to some still-earlier commit, and so on.

---

<sup>1</sup>Git makes this promise, but the [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) tells us that Git will fail someday.  The *size* of the hash IDs helps push that day far enough into the future that we will all be dead and not care.

<sup>2</sup>The breakage would be somewhat limited, but in general it would be a bad scene.

<sup>3</sup>You should always log *why* you made the commit.  Don't just say what you did: Git can compare this commit's snapshot to any other commit's snapshot, which will show *what you did*.  We can easily see that you changed line 42.  Tell us *why* you made that change: *why* did "the red ball" become "the blue cube", or whatever it was that you changed.  What was so bad about it being red, and a ball?

---

#### Branch names help us (and Git) find commits

Now that you know about commits—what you saw above is almost everything you need to *know*, although there's always more to learn—let's look at how we *find* the commits.  Remember that the hash IDs, like `H` and `G` in these illustrations, are actually big ugly random-looking things.  They're impossible for humans to remember.  We could write them down, but hang on, we have a *computer*.  Computers are good at this s—t: let's have the *computer* write down the hash ID.  Let's store hash IDs in a table of *names*, like branch names and tag names.

And that's what they are: a branch name is just an entry in a table that stores a hash ID.  If we have the name `main` in the table, and `main` stores the hash ID of `H`, we say that main *points to* `H`:

```
...--G--H   <-- main
```

We might add a new branch name `dev` or `feature` or whatever and switch to using that branch name, but that name *also* points to `H` at the moment:

```
...--G--H   <-- dev (HEAD), main
```

We (and Git) will use the special name `HEAD`, written in all uppercase like this, to remember which *name* we're using.  Then we'll have Git make a new commit—a new snapshot and metadata—with some changes in it vs the snapshot that Git has stored forever in `H`.  We'll call our new commit `I`, and `I` will point back to `H` like this:

```
          I
         /
...--G--H
```

The sneaky trick Git pulls is that when we have the name `dev` as our *current branch name*, and we make the new commit with `git commit`, Git *updates the branch name* to make it point to the new commit.  The other names, like `main`, don't change, so they still point to whatever commit they pointed to before; but `dev`, which has `HEAD` attached to it, now points to `I`:

```
          I   <-- dev (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- main
```

That's really all there is to this part of Git, but we've left out a few big important ideas, which I'll just touch on lightly.

#### Git's index and your working tree

The *snapshots* in commits are read-only and Git-only, using those compressed and de-duplicated files.  But your computer programs can't read those kinds of files, and some of your programs—like your editor—needs to be able to *write* files.  So the committed files are useless!  This is true of many version control systems (VCSes), not just Git.

To make the committed files useful, Git has to *extract* them from a commit, like extracting files from an archive.  (In fact, it's exactly like extracting from a compressed archive, except that archiving software doesn't use Git's weird internal format, which is only useful to Git itself.)  That's what `git switch` does, or `git checkout` in its branch-switching mode.<sup>4</sup>

When you work with Git, you generally work with these working copies of the files, which Git puts in something Git calls your *working tree* or *work-tree*.  These files are literally not *in* Git: at most, they were copied *out of* some commit, and might eventually be copied back into a future commit.  Note that if you damage or destroy these files, Git can extract any of its existing archives (commits), but can't get you any modifications you made.

In other VCSes, we get to stop here: there are the commits, and there is the working tree, and the VCS makes *new* commits from the working tree.  But Git is weird: Git makes *new* commits from something else.  Git calls this other thing the *index*, or the *staging area*, or (rarely now) the *cache*.  We won't go into proper detail here but this index is why you have to run `git add` so often: you're telling Git *copy my working tree file, which I've updated, back into your index to prepare it for committing*.  This compresses and de-duplicates the file (at `git add` time, which makes the later `git commit` go fast—with older VCSes one might run their commit verb, then take a coffee or lunch break because nothing was going to happen for many minutes).

Because the index holds *its own* copies (de-duplicated "copies") of files, you can have three different versions of some file going around at once: the `HEAD`, or current-commit, version is frozen for all time *in* the current commit, whatever its hash ID is.  There's a second copy (or "copy" when it's de-duplicated) of that file in the index, initially the same as the committed copy, but you can change that copy with `git add`; and there's a third copy of the file in your working tree, which you can change any time with any editor or anything you like.

It's therefore important to make sure that, before you run `git commit`, Git's *index* (or staging area) holds the copies you want Git to freeze for all time into the new commit.  That's why you will want to run `git diff` and `git status` and the like: to see if the index matches the `HEAD` commit, or the working tree, or both or neither, and if it *doesn't* match, `git diff --cached` or `git diff` can show you what's *different* about it.  But that's all we'll say about that here.

---

<sup>4</sup>In older (pre-2.23) Git versions you have only `git checkout`, so you must use the older command; it's slightly dangerous due to a minor design mistake.  This is corrected in Git 2.23, but you might as well start using `git switch` too if you have Git 2.23 or later.

---

#### Merging and merge commits

Eventually we always find ourselves having merge commits, for one reason or another.  Merges are good when they do what you want.  They're bad when they don't.  But because we *get* them and *make* them, we need to look at what they are about and how we make them.

We'll start by imagining our little repository has these commits in it:

```
          I--J   <-- br1 (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- br2
```

That is, we have at least two branches, named `br1` and `br2`.  Both branches started from some *shared* commits, which are the commits up through `H`, but after that someone made commits `I` and `J` on `br1`, and someone made commits `K` and `L` on `br2`.

We would now like to *combine the work* these two "someone"s did.  To do that, we pick one branch (`br1`) to be the current branch and commit, as we have done here.  Then we run:

```
git merge br2
```

The `br2` here is really just a way to have Git find the *commit* we want merged.  Branch names are normally used to find the the *commit* (or commits), and this is no exception: Git finds commit `L` because `br2` points to `L`.

The merge code now works its way backwards, as Git tends to do, from commit `J`—the current or `HEAD` commit on `br1`—and from commit `L`, at the same time.  This working-back discovers that commit `H` is the *best shared commit*, which Git calls the *merge base*.<sup>5</sup>

Git now does the work-finding step.  To figure out what we changed on `br1`, Git simply compares the snapshot in `H` to the snapshot in `J`: the tip commit of `br1`, where we are now.  This gets a diff that has a recipe that says to change particular lines of particular files:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-H> <hash-of-J>   # changes on br1
```

To figure out what they (whoever they are) did on `br2`, Git runs a second diff, starting from the *same merge base* `H`, but to `L` this time:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-H> <hash-of-L>   # changes on br2
```

The merge process is now a simple matter of *combining* the changes.  Whatever lines we changed, in whatever files, Git will make those changes, but Git will also make *their* changes, to whatever lines of whatever files they changed.  Git will apply the *combined* changes to the snapshot from commit `H`—the shared starting point, i.e., the merge base.

Conflicts, if they occur, generally happen because we and they changed the same lines, or lines that "touch", in the *same files*, but we and they did different things to those lines.  Git doesn't know whether to take ours, theirs, or both.  Git itself simply stops with a merge conflict and makes *you*, the programmer, figure out the correct result.  (Then you must finish the merge.)

If there are no such conflicts, however, Git will go on to make the merge commit on its own.  As with any commit, the merge commit will use the *current* commit as a parent.  What's special about a *merge* commit is that it will get a *second* parent: the commit we told Git to merge.  In this case, that's commit `L`:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M   <-- br1 (HEAD)
         \    /
          K--L   <-- br2
```

Like every commit, merge commit `M` has a snapshot, with all of the files in it (compressed and de-duplicated as usual).  Like any commit, merge commit `M` has metadata.  The only thing special about `M` is that its metadata lists *two* parents instead of the usual one.<sup>6</sup>  If there were merge conflicts, the snapshot in `M` is the one you, the programmer, told Git to make.  Otherwise it's the one Git figured out on its own (unless you used `--no-commit` to tweak the result, as in an [evil merge](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1461909/1256452)).

There is one especially-interesting side effect here, though.  Commits `K-L` used to be only "on" branch `br2`.  Now they're on *both branches*.  Commits `I-J` are still only on `br1`.  **The set of branches that contain any given commit is found by starting with all branch names, finding the commits they point to, and working backwards.**  If this process hits the commit you want to find out about, that commit is contained within that branch.  If more than one branch name contains the commit, more than one branch contains the commit.  (This, too, is peculiar to Git; most version control systems don't take this view.)

---

<sup>5</sup>In the illustration, we can work back one step at a time on both branches and meet at `H`, but in real cases we might have to go back just one hop on one branch, and many hops on another, for instance.  The actual algorithm for finding merge bases is the [Lowest Common Ancestor algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lowest_common_ancestor#Extension_to_directed_acyclic_graphs).  We'll skip over a number of important details here, including what Git does about the multiple-merge-bases case.

<sup>6</sup>A merge commit in Git can list more than two parents.  We won't cover how we have Git do this, but it doesn't require anything that we haven't already covered: it's still a commit with a snapshot and metadata.

---

#### Remotes and remote-tracking names

> ```
> Your branch and 'origin/devel' have diverged ...
> ```

The name `origin/devel` is what I call a *remote-tracking name*.  Git calls these *remote-tracking branch names*, but I find the word *branch* here adds nothing and just makes for confusion.  `origin/devel` *is* a *name*, and it does "track something remote", but it's not a *branch* name: no more than a tag name is a branch name for instance.

What's going on here is that your Git software is talking to another Git repository.  Your repository has branch names, like `devel` or whatever.  But these are *your* branch names: you run `git switch devel`, and then do some work and run `git commit`, and now the hash ID stored *in* the branch name is the hash ID of some new commit `I` that you made.

Your Git software must therefore be careful *not* to stomp on *your* branch names, just because their Git repository, over on GitHub or wherever it might be, has a branch name `devel`.  So your Git will create or update the name `origin/devel` instead, every time you use the name `origin`—a *remote*, as Git calls it—to have your Git software call up their Git software and get any commits they have that you don't.  Your Git sees that they have a branch named `devel`, so your Git gets their latest `devel` commit hash ID.  If your Git repository doesn't have that commit, your Git gets that commit from them and stuffs it into your repository, along with any parent commits needed, and so on, and now you have their `devel` branch.  But you can't have it called `devel`, so your Git software uses `origin/devel` instead:

```
          I--J--K   <-- devel (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H
         \
          L   <-- origin/devel
```

This setup is the same as when we had two branches in your repository.  In fact, we *do* have two branches, if by *branch* we mean *interesting subset of commits* rather than *thing found via branch name*.  (See also [What exactly do we mean by "branch"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25068543/1256452))

We can *merge* these:

```
          I--J--K
         /       \
...--G--H         M   <-- devel (HEAD)
         \ ______/
          L   <-- origin/devel
```

and when we do, commit `L` is now on `devel`.

#### The `HEAD~n` syntax

You ran:

> ```
> git rebase -i HEAD~9
> ```

When we have simple, linear graphs:

```
...--G--H--I--J--K--L   <-- main (HEAD)
```

the tilde `~` syntax, `HEAD~5` for instance, simply counts back five commits: `L`, `K`, `J`, `I`, H`.  So` HEAD~5`or`main~5`means *commit`H`*.  There's only one path backwards and we take that one path and count hops and that's it.

When we have complicated graphs, with branch-and-merge constructions in them:

```
          G--H--I
         /       \
...--E--F         M--N   <-- devel (HEAD)
         \       /
          J--K--L
```

this is no longer the case.  We now have *two* paths backwards.  Starting from `HEAD` or `devel`, which means commit `N`, we can move back one hop to `M`.  But now we can move back one more hop to *either* `I` *or* `L`.  Which hop should we take?

Git's answer to this is to designate one of the parent links as the *first* parent.  All others are "less interesting" (though if you want, you can pick them out with the hat or caret `^` suffix).  So `HEAD~5` here means *follow the first parent out of `M`*.  Counting five commits on *this* path, we get `N`, `M`, `I`, `H`, `G`: `HEAD~5` means *commit `G`*.

Going one more hop, `HEAD~6`, means *commit `F`*.  Note that having arrived at `G`, there's only one path backwards to `F`.  Interestingly, a *branch apart* in the "forwards" direction—the direction Git *doesn't* use—is a *merge together* in the "backwards" direction that Git does use, and a merge commit acts as a branch-apart, not a merge-together, when we work backwards.  Since Git *does* work backwards, Git's view is very different from the average human's here.

When you want to understand these things in detail, always look at it from Git's point of view:

> ```
> and have 6 and 2 different commits each, respectively
> ```

This means that *your current branch* (presumably `devel`) has six commits on it that `origin/devel` lacks, and `origin/devel` has two commits on it that your branch lacks.  If we draw that out, we get a picture like this:

```
       E--F--G--H--I--J   <-- devel (HEAD)
      /
...--D
      \
       K--------------L   <-- origin/devel
```

If we count hops from `J` backwards, it takes 7 to get to `D`.  So to name commit `D` you'd just want `HEAD~7`—or you can run `git log` or `git log --decorate --graph --oneline` and cut and paste the raw hash ID of the commit, which is often easier than counting hops like this.

#### We're finally ready for rebase

As noted above, when we use `git rebase`, we're saying *there's good stuff in our commits, but we don't like something about them*.  What exactly we *don't* like determines the kind of rebase we'll run.  Rebase is a high-powered tool, and something of a [Swiss Army chainsaw](http://catb.org/%7Eesr/jargon/html/S/Swiss-Army-chainsaw.html) of a command, but at its heart it copies commits.

Before we get into the details, we should note that there is a Git command that copies *one* commit, that is much simpler to use: `git cherry-pick`.  To use `git cherry-pick`, we check out / switch to some branch:

```
git switch copy-goes-here
```

resulting in:

```
...--o--o--P--C--o--o   <-- somebranch
      \
       o--o--H   <-- copy-goes-here (HEAD)
```

where the `o`s represent commits whose hash IDs we don't really care about.  Meanwhile commit `C` is the one we want to "copy".  It makes some *change*—that is, its snapshot, when compared to that of its parent `P`, says *change this file and/or that other file*, and the *change* it makes is the change we *want to make* to commit `H`.  Commit `C` also has a commit log message and an author and so on in its metadata, and `git cherry-pick` will copy most of these as well.  So we now run:

```
git cherry-pick <hash-of-C>
```

Git finds the diff from `P` to `C` and applies *that* diff to our current commit `H`.  Technically, Git uses the same internal machinery that it uses for a merge, as it runs *two* `git diff` commands, one from `P` to `H` to see "what we changed" (to keep these changes) and one from `P` to `C` to see "what they changed" (to add their changes).  It then combines the changes, just like any merge.  The special thing it does then, though, is to make a new commit `C'` that's *like* `C` but:

- has `H` as its parent; and
- has us as the *committer* (separate from the *author* in the metadata)

and it is *not* a merge commit.  It does not "remember" the hash ID of commit `C` (although you can use `-x` to add this to the log message).

The new copy `C'` gets a different hash ID and we now have:

```
...--o--o--P--C--o--o   <-- somebranch
      \
       o--o--H--C'  <-- copy-goes-here (HEAD)
```

Note that Git updated the branch name as usual, so `copy-goes-here` now points to `C'`, which points back to `H`.  The original commits `P` and `C` are undisturbed (necessarily so: no commit can ever be changed).

A *typical* rebase is used to, well, re-do the "base" of some branch:

```
          A--B--C   <-- topic (HEAD)
         /
...--o--*--D--E   <-- origin/topic
```

What we *like* about commits `A-B-C` is, well, everything *except* that the *parent* of commit `A` is commit `*`.  We want to put `A-B-C` after commit `E`:

```
          A--B--C   [abandoned]
         /
...--o--*--D--E   <-- origin/topic
               \
                A'-B'-C'  <-- topic (HEAD)
```

The original `A-B-C` chain of commits can't be changed, or even destroyed yet, but we can simply *stop using them*.  Git forces the name `topic` to point to `C'` instead of `C`, in the end.  Since humans don't remember hash IDs, they'll use the name `topic` to find the latest commit and get `C'` instead of `C`.  They're so dumb, they'll think `C'` *is* `C`.   And that's quite often exactly what we want.  (It's probably something you would like, in this case, but you can do that later.)

Anyway, for rebase to do its job, then, Git needs to know:

- Which commits should Git copy?
- Where should Git put the copies?

The `git rebase` command cleverly gets *both pieces of information* from a *single argument*.  We run:

```
git switch topic
```

so that we're on the right branch to begin with.  Then we run:

```
git rebase origin/topic
```

The name `origin/topic` selects commit `E`.  That's a commit Git *should not copy*, but Git uses its usual scan-backwards trick too: Git won't copy `D` either, nor `*`, nor any of the earlier commits.

The commits that Git *will* copy, if not stopped by a "don't copy", are those that end where the current commit is, i.e., commits `C`, and `B`, and `A`, and `*`, and everything earlier.  But the `origin/topic` tells Git: *don't copy `*` or anything earlier*.  So that *stops* Git from copying too many commits.

Meanwhile, the *where to put the copies* is: after commit `E`, as found by the name `origin/topic`.  So the copies go after `E`.

A non-interactive rebase now simply checks out commit `E` directly, then copies `A`, `B`, and `C` one at a time, as if with, or literally with, `git cherry-pick`.  Then it yanks the *name* `topic`—the branch we were on—over to point to the last-copied commit.

An interactive rebase does the same thing, but opens the editor on the list of `pick` instructions for each cherry-pick.

#### Rebasing with merges

In your case, you made a mistake of sorts (not really a big one, but it would have been easier to do this without it): you had Git merge your `devel` with `origin/devel`.  That is, from:

```
       E--F--G--H--I--J   <-- devel (HEAD)
      /
...--D
      \
       K--------------L   <-- origin/devel
```

you had Git run `git merge origin/devel` or equivalent.  (You probably ran `git pull`: Git newbies should generally *avoid* `git pull`, in my opinion, but that's just an opinion.)

The result was this:

```
             E--F--G--H--I--J
            /                \
...--B--C--D                  M   <-- devel (HEAD)
            \                /
             K--------------L   <-- origin/devel
```

You then ran `git rebase -i HEAD~9`.  Counting 9 hops backwards, along the first parent of merge commit `M`, reaches commit `B`.  So the commit you tell `git rebase -i` *not* to copy is commit `B`, or anything earlier.

Rebase now lists out all the commits that it *should* copy.  As you found, the default is to *drop merge commits entirely*.  The remaining commit list is: `C`, `D`, then one of `E` or `K` and then the rest of the commits along that row,<sup>7</sup> then the commits along the other row.  Commit `M`, since it *is* a merge, is dropped from the `pick` list.

If you leave the list unmodified and let the merge operation run, it will copy this set of commits, one at a time.  The copies will go after commit `B`, so we'll have something like this:

```
...--B--C'-D'-E'-...-L'  <-- devel (HEAD)
      \
       C--D--...--M   [abandoned]
           \     /
            K---L   <-- origin/devel
```

However, `git rebase` tries to be clever, if it can, and *re-use* `C` and `D` directly; it can, so it will, unless you tell it not to; but the effect is very similar to what I drew here.  If you alter the `pick` lines, you can of course get many other effects, and we don't know whether `K'-L'` come right after `D` or right before the end.

If you *do* prefer the *merge*, however, you can use `git rebase -i -r`.  When you do this you get a more complicated instruction sheet, with `label` commands in it.  This helps the rebase code rebuild the merges.  Instead of *just* running a series of cherry-pick commands, Git can remember hash IDs as it works, and then run `git merge` commands.  So it can *produce* this:

```
             EFI-H'-GJ
            /         \
...--B--C--D           M'  <-- devel (HEAD)
            \         /
             K-------L   <-- origin/devel
```

if you want, by leaving the original `D` and `K` and `L` alone, combining `E` and `F` and `I` into one new commit, copying `H` to `H'`, combining `G` and `J` into one commit, and then doing a `git merge` to merge `GJ` and `L` together to make `M'`.  (As usual the originals will still all be in the repository, undisturbed, just a bit hard to find: `ORIG_HEAD` and reflogs will hold their hash IDs for some time though.)

Using `git rebase -i -r <hash-of-D>` (or `HEAD~7`, but I usually find `git log` and cut-and-paste is easier here) would be a way to do this all at once.  It all depends on what you want as your final outcome, and how comfortable you are trying to do it in a single step, vs multiple separate steps.

---

<sup>7</sup>Rebase uses `--topo-order` internally to ensure this; without `--topo-order` there are more possible orders that intermix the rows.