# git rebase and keep branches of rebased branch that has merges without manually resolving conflicts

Tags: git, git-merge, rebase, git-rebase

When I have a git graph that lookslike this:

```
A - B - C
      \
        E - F - G - H
          \       /
            I - J
```

is it possible and if yes what commands do I need to use to come to a  structure that is like this:

```
A - B - C - E - F - G - H
              \       /
                I - J
```

I have tried git rebase with lots of options but I haven't come to the result i want.

I tried with the --onto option but it creates a single branch and I need to solve conflict manually.

Comment: I think I found the answer and it would be to use `--rebase-merges`. The only problem that still exists now is that I get conflicts at every merge that follows and there are many of them in my case.

Comment: `--rebase-merges` *is* the correct option. Note that the result is *new commits* with new and different hash IDs, though, so the second drawing should use `E'`, `F',` etc., or some other way to denote the fact that these are new and different commits. You can expect to get the same merge conflicts you got when you made original merge `H`, in general, although the specifics of commit `C` might change this somewhat.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rebasing a Git merge commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783599/rebasing-a-git-merge-commit)

Comment: @mkrieger1 Quite similar problem but what I asked for was a way to not have to manually solve merge conflicts again. The solution I provide actually makes  that possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the actual way to do it and not have to resolve manually the conflicts is to use the rerere git's feature. The rerere is used to keep the conflicts resolutions and apply them when they are encountered again in a merge. There is a handfull script that is in the git repo called [rerere-train.sh](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/rerere-train.sh) to train manually the rerere with merge conflicts resolutions from past merge commits.

So to answer my original question the following commands need to be run after downloading the `rerere-train.sh` script to the parent directory:

```bash
git config rerere.enabled true
../rerere-train.sh H
git checkout H
git rebase --rebase-merges C
git commit -a
# Here you save the commit message of the merge
git rebase --continue
```

For more merges in the rebased branch rerere-train.sh can be used before the rebase for each merge.

Answer (score 1):

Simply add `--rebase-merges` to your `rebase` command. If there are merge conflicts, just resolve them. Take your time and be patient.

Here's proof that this will work. We start with this topology:

```
*   1c69c6d (HEAD -> br) h
|\  
| * 2e08ae7 j
| * e9a2d44 i
* | 2e831e6 g
* | 19d765f f
|/  
* dd465e4 e
| * 5167934 (main) c
|/  
* ec99741 b
* 0f9a759 a
```

Satisfy yourself that this is identical to the topology of your first diagram. Now:

```
% git rebase --rebase-merges main
```

Result:

```
*   627ddfe (HEAD -> br) h
|\  
| * 2734bc2 j
| * 89fb7ba i
* | 4cbffe3 g
* | badcc53 f
|/  
* b239c38 e
* 5167934 (main) c
* ec99741 b
* 0f9a759 a
```

Again, satisfy yourself that this topology is identical to your second diagram. QED.

(As you've been told in a comment, the SHA of most of the commits inevitably change; that's what a rebase is. But they are the right commits, as the copied commit messages show.)

Comment: Yes I had tried this option but the problem was that there were multiple merges with many conflicts so I couldn't solve each one of them again. The answer for this would be the usage of git rerere that could save the merge conflicts resolutions as I answered myself after you.

Comment: Very nice! Yes, in real life, this sort of rebase is very prone to result in merge conflicts, and if you find those tedious and repetitive, that is exactly what `git rerere` is for.