# How to move a merge commit earlier in history?

Tags: git

I have the following git history (from oldest `A` to newest `D` commits):

```
mybranch:
commit A
commit B
...
merge main into mybranch
commit C
commit D
...
```

I'd like to modify it to:

```
mybranch:
merge main into mybranch
commit A
commit B
...
commit C
commit D
...
```

How can I do this? I thought to use `git rebase -i` but that does not seem to allow reordering commits while preserving the merge commit.

Comment: You can merge `main` again into your branch. It works and it should produce the outcome that you desire.

Comment: You could rebase, removing the merge, and then merge again?

Comment: @axiac if I merge again, I think the merge commit will be most recent in history. I'd like it to be moved further back.

Comment: The question is misleading. I though that the most recent commits are on top.

Comment: Further back? The question makes it seem like you want it to be the most recent commit. You can pause the rebase, merge, and then continue?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4784082/7976758 `git rebase -i --rebase-merges`

Comment: I updated to clarify the history order. Sorry about that.

Comment: Your branch is a working branch. You should squash it into a single commit before making a PR (or before merging it back into `main`). The commits on your branch, their order or when you have merged `main` in it should not matter.

Comment: @phd the git rebase documentation says -i and rebase-merges are not compatible together

Comment: @axiac I cannot squash my branch based on rules of our CI strategy.

Comment: Re-read https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#_rebasing_merges

Comment: You can squash (it's a local operation) but you probably cannot push with `--force`. If this happens, you won't be able to push after you move the merge commit either. If you did not already push then you can do whatever you want on your local repo.