# How to rebase only the commits after the latest merge?

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-pull

Consider following scenario:

1. I checked out a branch from master
2. I made some commits
3. I merged updated master
4. I made some more commits
5. Now I want rebase commits from point 4 so that commits from point 2 are not affected.

So if I have initially:

```
     (1)         (2)
x--x--x--x--x--x--x         master
       \     \
        y--y--Y--y--y       dev
          (2)(3)   (4)
```

I want to get:

```
     (1)         (2)
x--x--x--x--x--x--x             master
       \           \
        y--y--------Y'--y'--y'  dev
          (2)      (5)     (5)
```

If I just do `git rebase master` it will rebase commits both from 2 and from 4 and delete merge from 3. It's not what I want.

There is also option to do `git merge master`, then `git rebase -i -p` before the merge commit from 3 and move the last merge after the merge from 3 and do fixup/squash it into the merge from 3. **Update**: it does not work that easy. Git refuses to squash two merges. This problem: [git rebase interactive: squash merge commits together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1725708/git-rebase-interactive-squash-merge-commits-together) .

Comment: My answer stands (except I mistakenly reference the operation as a `merge --onto`: it is `rebase --onto`). I have update the answer to come *closer* to what you want.

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: Refusing to squash a merge: 987ab25995f24554cc7ce1451919327e09c5a18b

Comment: Ok. I guess the `reset --soft` mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/q/1725708/6309 can help. Not sure of the exact sequence though.

Answer (score 3):

Using my and VonC's answers made more automate-able solution:

```
git checkout -b tmp Y
git merge master 
git reset --soft HEAD^^ 
git rev-parse master > .git/MERGE_HEAD 
git commit -C Y
git checkout -
git rebase --onto tmp Y
git branch -d tmp
```

Y - is the merge commit to be extended.

And it works like this:

```
x--x--x--x--x--x--x         master
       \     \
        y--y--Y--y--y       dev

x--x--x--x--x--x--x         master
      |      \
       \      Y             tmp
        \    / \
         y--y   y--y        dev

x--x--x--x--x--x--x         master
      |      \     \
       \      Y-----Y'      tmp
        \    / \
         y--y   y--y        dev

x--x--x--x--x--x--x         master
      |            \
      |      -------Y'      tmp
       \    /
        y--y--Y--y--y       dev

x--x--x--x--x--x--x         master
      |            \
      |      -------Y'      tmp
       \    /        \
        y--y          y--y  dev

x--x--x--x--x--x--x           master
       \           \
        y--y--------Y'--y--y  dev
```

Answer (score 2):

You start from:

```
     (1)
x--x--x--x--x--x--x         master
       \     \
        y--y--Y--y--y       dev
          (2)(3)   (4)
```

Do a [`git rebase --onto`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase):

```
git branch dev1 Y^
git rebase --onto master Y^ dev
```

`Y^` references the first parent of the merge commit `Y`: here '`y`', and not '`x`'.
See "[Ancestry References](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection#Ancestry-References)":

> The first parent is the branch you were on when you merged, and the second is the commit on the branch that you merged in.

You would end up with:

```
     (1)
x--x--x--x--x--x--x             master
       \           \
        y--y        Y'--y'--y'  dev
          (2)      (5)
        (dev1)
```

That would split your initial `dev` branch in two, and apply only the last `dev` commits on top of `master`, while keeping the first `dev` commits unchanged, now referenced by the branch `dev1`.

You can try a:

```
git rebase -p --onto master `Y^` dev
```

to see if that preserve the relationship between between `y` (that is `Y^`) and the newly rebased `Y'`. But I doubt that is possible.

`-p` is for `--preserve-merge`.

Answer (score 1):

I end up doing the following:

```
git rebase -i -p Y^
```

In the file add the following line after line with the merge (presumably after the first line):

```
exec sh -c "git merge master; git reset --soft HEAD^^; git rev-parse master > .git/MERGE_HEAD; git commit -C `git rev-parse HEAD`"
```

Comment: Sound great. More precise than my answer. +1