# Rebase against the main branch

Tags: git

There are two branches. The main branch and branch with one feature. But the feature branch is in conflict with the main. People told me, that I should rebase the feature branch against the main.

Does it mean `git rebase origin/main` (and I am on the feature branch) or `git rebase feature_branch` (and I am on the main branch)?

It is important that during the `git merge PRODUCTION` there should be no conflict and it has to be solved by the command rebase. How?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That would mean:

```
git fetch
git checkout feature
git rebase origin/main
```

You replay locally `feature` branch on top of the updated `origin/main`.
That gives you a chance to resolve any conflict locally, and *then* push the feature branch (a `git push --force` since its history has changed): make sure you are the only one working on that branch.

(as [aduch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2389720/aduch) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32426984/rebase-against-the-main-branch/32426998#comment52719747_32426998), if there were merges from `origin/main` to `feature` before, then a `git rebase -p origin/main` could be needed in theory. See "[How to rebase only the commits after the latest merge?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18978494/6309)".
But that would also mean that, in that case, a git merge would be preferable to a git rebase, which have the added complexity of preserving past merges)

If you were not the only one working on that branch, then an alternative would be to merge `origin/main` to `feature`, solving any conflict there, before pushing `feature` (regular push).

Comment: I did the three steps, then I resolved conflicts. And then I was not on any branch. Before commit it asked if I want to switch to some branch, I wanted to commit it to, so I switched to feature branch, there was conflict between the actual things and the feature branch, I merged it and now I am where I was before. The feature branch is still in conflict with the main.

Comment: @user3599497 try the same step in a new clone. Make sure you can cleanly checkout feature (there should be no message). Then start the merge.

Comment: Isn't `-p` option recommended to preserve merge commits?

Comment: @aduch only if there were merge commits to preserve... in which case, I wouldn't do a rebase anyway. I would do a new merge. I have edited the answer to reflect your comment.