# How to join last N merge commits into one?

Tags: git

In my repository I currently have this history:

```
$ git log --oneline
<commit-id-1> Merge commit '<merged-commit-id-1>' into <branch>
<commit-id-2> Merge commit '<merged-commit-id-2>' into <branch>
...
```

where `<merged-commit-id-1>` and `<merged-commit-id-2>` were merged from another branch from which I created the current `branch` previously. Now I want to join those merge commit into one somehow:

```
$ git log --oneline
<commit-id> My message about huge successful merge here...
...
```

I tried

```
$ git rebase --preserve-merges -i HEAD~2
```

with `p` and `s` but get this error:

```
Refusing to squash a merge: ...
```

(I also reproduced it in a new simplest possible repository) Is there a way around it?

What I really want is to be able to merge a lot of commits by their IDs from the original branch (which was changed) while resolving conflicts gradually and not introducing dozens of merge commits (`merge --squash` is not an option either, since I need to preserve the history).

---

Example:

```
$ git init
$ echo 1 > 1; git add 1; git commit -m 1
$ git branch branch
$ echo 2 > 2; git add 2; git commit -m 2
$ echo 3 > 3; git add 3; git commit -m 3
$ git checkout branch
$ echo 4 > 4; git add 4; git commit -m 4
$ git log master --oneline
8222... 3
1f03... 2
... 1
$ git merge 1f03
# in real project here goes some work
$ git merge 8222
# and here, can't merge 8222 right away, because it can be difficult
# now need to clean up merge commits OR merge incrementally in a different way
$ git rebase -i --preserve-merges HEAD~2 
p ...
s ...
Refusing to squash a merge: a199... (merge commit for 8222)
```

---

Solution by torek:

```
git update-ref refs/heads/branch `git commit-tree -p branch~N -p 8222 branch^{tree} -m 'Commit message for a new merge commit'`
```

Comment: Possible (weak) dupe:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/1725708/1079354

Comment: I've seen this, but hope for some simple example (added a scenario in the question).

Comment: I found [a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563632/how-can-i-merge-two-commits-into-one), do you need this? :)

Comment: This is what I do with `git rebase --preserve-merges -i HEAD~2` (need `--preserve-merges` for merge commits), but I get this `Refusing to squash a merge` error (and I do rebase from a clean state ofc).

Comment: If you mean to merge 3+ branches/commits into one merge commit, then just do `git merge b1 b2 b3 ...`, all 3 branches will be merged into your current branch, you probably need to use `git mergetool` to clean things up.

Comment: @ryenus, but `git merge b1 b2 b3` where `b1`, `b2` and `b3` are chronological from the same branch is equivalent to just `git merge b3`? I can't do this (otherwise I would just `merge master`), this is not (only) about git conflicts, there are also build and test errors as well as possible bugs, so I want to merge only one chunk of `master`'s history at a time, resolve git conflicts and then work with code for a bit before merging another commit.

Comment: @user5365198, `git merge b1 b2 b3` is supposed to be performed when none of them is merged yet. If you want one such merge commit, but still want to merge commit-by-commit, the answer is probably no.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First some background ... merging, in git, has two functions:

1. It compares the "merge base" of two lines of development to the two tip commits, and then combines the changes, using a semi-intelligent<sup>1</sup> algorithm.  That is, `git merge other` first computes `$base`,<sup>2</sup> then does `git diff $base HEAD` and `git diff $base other`.  These two diffs tell git what you want done to `$base`, e.g., add a line to `foo.txt`, remove a line from `bar.tex`, and change a line in `xyz.py`.  Git then tries to keep all these changes, and if the line added to `foo.txt` was added the *same* way in *each* branch, or the same line was *removed* from `bar.tex`, just keep *one copy* of the change.
2. It records, for future use, the fact that two lines of development were brought together, and that all the desired changes from both lines are now present in the "merge commit".  The resulting commit is therefore suitable as a new merge-base, for example.  We'll see something like this (not exactly this) in a moment.

These two functions are implemented in quite different ways.  The first one is done by merging the diffs in your work-tree, leaving any too-difficult cases for you to handle manually.  The second one is done at the time you make the merge commit, by listing two<sup>3</sup> "parent commit IDs" in the new (merge) commit.

What you'll need to decide is how much of this to preserve, in what way.  I think it helps immensely, in these cases, to draw (part of) the commit graph.

Here, in your example you start with a common base, which I will call `B` (for base), then have two more commits on `master` and one on `branch`:

```
B - C - D    <-- master
  \
    E   <-- branch
```

Now on `branch` you first merge commit `C`:

```
B - C - D   <-- master
  \   \
    E - F   <-- branch
```

Whether this needs manual intervention depends on the change from `B` to `C`, and the change from `B` to `E`, but in any case this makes new merge commit `F`.

You then ask git to merge in commit `D`.  This, however, no longer uses commit `B` as the merge base, because following the new merge `F` backwards, git finds that the merge base—the most recent commit—between `branch` and `master`—is now commit `C`.  The comparisons are therefore `C` to `D`, and `C` to `F`.  Git combines these (perhaps having to stop and get help); when someone (you or git) commits the result, we get:

```
B - C - D   <-- master
  \   \   \
    E - F - G   <-- branch
```

Now, you're asking (I think) to "squash" F and G into a single merge commit.  Given the way git works, you can only achieve this by creating a *new* merge commit, then making `branch` point to it (dropping the reference to `G` and hence the only reference to `F` as well).

There are two things to consider when making this new merge commit:

- What tree (set of files/directories attached to the commit, will be made out of the index/staging-area) do you want?  You can only have one!
- What parent commits do you want to list?  To make it come right after commit `E`, you want its "first parent" to be `E`.  To make it a merge commit, it must have at least one other parent.

The tree to choose is obvious: commit `G` has the desired merge-result, so use the tree from `G`.

The second (and perhaps third) parent to use is less obvious.  It's possible to list both `C` *and* `D`, giving an octopus merge `O`:

```
B - C = D   <-- master
  \    \ \
    E --- O   <-- branch
```

But this doesn't *do* anything particularly useful, because `C` is an ancestor of `D`.  If you made a more normal-looking merge commit `M` that just points back to both `E` (as first parent) and `D`) (as second parent), you'd get this:

```
B - C - D   <-- master
  \      \
    E ---- M   <-- branch
```

This would be "just as good" as the octopus merge: it has the same tree (we're picking the tree out of commit `G` each time) and it has the same first-parent (`E`).  It has just one other parent (i.e., `D`), but that causes `C` to be in its history, so it doesn't need an explicit connection directly to `C`.

(It *can* have an explicit connection, if you want one, but there's no particularly good reason to give it one.)

That leaves one last problem: the mechanics of actually producing this merge (`M` or `O`, whichever you prefer) and getting `branch` to point to it.

There's a "plumbing" command that creates it directly, assuming you're in this state at the moment:

```
B - C - D   <-- master
  \   \   \
    E - F - G   <-- branch
```

At this point you can run (note, these are untested):

```
$ commit=$(git commit-tree -p branch~2 -p master branch^{tree} < msg)
```

where `msg` is a file containing the desired commit message.  This creates commit `M` (with just the two parents, the first one being commit `E`, i.e., `branch~2` and the second being commit `D`, i.e., `master`).  Then:

```
$ git update-ref refs/heads/branch $commit
```

It's possible to create `M` using just ordinary git "porcelain" commands, but it requires a bit more trickiness.  First we want to save the desired tree, i.e., `branch^{tree}`:

```
$ tree=$(git rev-parse branch^{tree})
```

Then, while on branch `branch` (because `git reset` will use the current branch), tell git to back up two commits.  It doesn't matter whether we use soft, hard, or mixed reset here, we're just rewinding the label `branch` for the moment:

```
$ git reset HEAD~2
```

Then, tell git we're merging `master`, but don't commit no matter what.  (This is just to get git to set up `.git/MERGE_MSG` and `.git/MERGE_HEAD` -- you could write those files directly, instead of doing this part.)

```
$ git merge --no-commit master
```

Then wipe out whatever's in the work tree and index, replacing it all with the saved tree from commit `G` instead:

```
$ git rm -rf .; git checkout $tree -- .
```

(you'll need to be in the top level directory of the work tree for this).  This prepares the index for the new commit, and now there's just that one last commit to make:

```
$ git commit
```

This commits the merge, using the tree whose ID we grabbed before doing the `git reset`.  The `git reset` made the tip commit of `branch` be commit `E`, so our new commit is merge-commit `M`, the same as if we had used the low level plumbing commands.

(Note: `git rebase -i -p` can't quite do this, it's not smart enough to know when this is OK—which is only when we have set it up to be OK in the first place.)

---

<sup>1</sup>It's not particularly smart, but it handles the easy cases pretty well.

<sup>2</sup>You can compute this yourself using `git merge-base`, with `base=$(git merge-base other)`.  For some (uncommon but not as rare as one might hope) cases, though, there may be more than one suitable merge base.  The default merge algorithm ("recursive") will merge two merge-bases to come up with a "virtual base" and use that.  So there are some subtle differences if you try to do this all manually.

<sup>3</sup>There can be more than two parents: the definition of a "merge commit" is any commit with more than one parent.  Multi-way merges ("octopus" merges) are done differently, though (using the "octopus merge" strategy).  So, for the most part, I'm ignoring these here.

Comment: Thank you for this method and an explanation, it certainly works for my example. I will try to use it (so `git commit-tree -p branch~N -p some-id` where `some-id` is the last commit I merged that is also in a middle of `master` somewhere). For those commits like `F` and `G`, do I need `gc`/`prune`, or it's ok to let them be?

Comment: You can leave the old commits around: that's what happens when you do a `git rebase` (interactive or not), for instance.  All you are doing with this kind of two-stage merge followed by "special rebase" (that only works for this case) is a special kind of rebase, after all.